# Fire batch (.bat) file execution and continue

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a .bat file that starts executing another few .bat files, *without waiting* for the 1st to complete before going to the next one. Spawning multiple cmd.exe commands is OK.

I tried doing

```
call script1.bat
call script2.bat
```

from the "main" batch file, but this runs synchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way of accomplishing this by using `start` instead of `call`:

```
start script1.bat
start script2.bat
```

This works pretty much like double-clicking the script files, only from the command-line :-)